# skybound's GeckoWebBrowser gives "The connection is Untrusted" while running https site

Tags: vb.net, https, webbrowser-control, ssl-certificate, gecko

I am using Skybound's GeckoWebBrowser to access some site and it works fine with http. If I use a particular https site with certificate it gives error."This Connection is Untrusted".

This site is opening through Firefox after I added a certificate provided by the site in Servers tab.

But when I use GeckoWebBrowser to access this site it gives "This Connection is untrusted" error.

What do I do ? How do I make this site trusted programmatically or how do I add certificate programmatically to GeckWebBrowser.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the file cert_override.txt file from Firefox folder to C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Geckofx\10902\DefaultProfile folder and it worked fine.
This is the profile folder used by geckowebbrowser